# Xcode 11 XCTestPlan can't export screenshots

Tags: ios, xcode, xctestplan

In Xcode 11, I created a xctestplan for exporting localized screenshots, but I can't select "**Include screenshots**" option. Like this image, the warning message is "Screenshot for localization issue."

[image]

If I check the report of the UI test, then I can see the screenshots files are there, and I can save them.

[image]

If I export it, in the "**Notes**" folder no screenshots, any help?

In the configurations of xctestplan, I set 
`Automatic Screenshots` -> `On, and keep all`, `Localization Screenshots` -> `On`

Answer (score 2):

I restarted Xcode and cleaned the project; it works finally!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and a restart/clean doesn't solve it...

Comment: Could you try restart your mac too?

Comment: You're right! I had to reboot the system, and then it worked. I wasted hours on this ridiculous bug... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Spoke to an engineer at WWDC20. In the xctestplan, it turns out that if you don't set the Application Region from System Region to a specific region for the different variants, the files generated end up missing information. Then a quick deletion of the app's folder in DerivedData fixed the issue.

Comment: I had to set both *Application Region* and *Application Language* in my test plan configuration before exporting the localization catalog would include the relevant screenshots.

Comment: yeah, I was setting the application language of course :)